# Getting URL from flask webapp and saving scraped items in a SQLite3 database. Not sure if process_item is called or not

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, scrapy

Sorry about the long post. As I mentioned in the title I have a flask web app that takes in a url and sends it to the scrapy spider. The spider then goes through the response and scrapes the src of all found images.

Spider code:

```
class ContentspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'content'
myBaseUrl = ''
start_urls = []

def __init__(self, category='', **kwargs): #The category variable will have the input URL.
    self.myBaseUrl = category
    self.start_urls.append(self.myBaseUrl)
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def parse(self, response):

    item = WebItem()

    images = response.css('img')

    for img in images:
        src = img.css('img::attr(src)').get()

        item['src'] = src

        yield item
```

The scraped items are returned as a json file. This is the flask code in which that happens:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

output_data = []
crawl_runner = CrawlerRunner()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        s = request.form['url']
        global baseURL 
        baseURL = s

        return redirect(url_for('scrape'))

@app.route('/scrape')
def scrape():
    scrape_with_crochet(baseURL=baseURL) #passing the URL to the scraping function
    time.sleep(20)
    return jsonify(output_data)

@crochet.run_in_reactor
def scrape_with_crochet(baseURL):
    # This will connect to the dispatcher that will kind of loop the code between these two functions.
    dispatcher.connect(_crawl_result, signal=signals.item_scraped)

    # This will connect to the ReviewspiderSpider function in our scrapy file and after each yield will pass to the crawler_result function.
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(ContentspiderSpider, category = baseURL)
    return eventual

#this will append the data to the output data list
def _crawl_result(item, response, spider):
    output_data.append(dict(item))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, I expect the items to be saved in a db file as well. As I wrote this in the scrapy pipeline:

```
class WebappScraperPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('imgaes.db')
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS images_tb""")

        self.curr.execute("""CREATE TABLE images_tb(source text)""")

    def save_images(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""INSERT INTO images_tb VALUES(?)""",(
                                                                    item['src'],
                                                                                ))
        self.conn.commit()


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.save_images(item)
        return item
```

But that does not seem to be working for some reason. I am not sure if the items are being passed to the pipeline, I am guessing that is the problem. I apologize for the lack of my knowledge as I am new to this but I am lost and need help figuring this out. I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/integrating-scrapy-with-flask-8611debc4579)

The json file is output but I get this error in the console:

```
Unhandled error in EventualResult
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python projects\tests\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 460, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "D:\python projects\tests\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 568, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "D:\python projects\tests\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\python projects\tests\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1475, in gotResult
    _inlineCallbacks(r, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "D:\python projects\tests\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
```

Comment: Did you **enable** this pipeline somewhere?

Comment: @gangabass Yes. It is enabled in the settings.py

Comment: any errors in a Scrapy log output?

Comment: @gangabass updated my post with the error message.

Comment: That traceback seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the pipeline was not enabled. `CrawlerRunner` requires passing the settings object explicitly.

```
from scrapy.settings import settings
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings 

s = get_project_settings
crawl_runner = CrawlerRunner(s)
```